# How do you URL-encode the @ symbol in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, urlencode

Using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding to URL-encode an NSString isn't encoding the @ symbol.  What's the proper way to resolve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this after the line of code you already have (and change the receiver, etc. to your own variables):

```
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
```

If you want to make sure that everything is encoded, here is the best way:

```
NSMutableString *escaped = [actionString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];       
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"%3B" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"%40" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"%09" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"%23" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"%3C" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"%3E" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%22" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
[escaped replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"%0A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:wholeString];
```

(from Roger @ [Iphone SDk : Issue with ampersand in the URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-problem-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string))

Answer (score 7):

The best way to URL encode is with this, from my blog post http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/ :

```
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
  NULL,
  (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
  NULL,
  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
  kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Comment: The above code works great but its missing a few characters that need to be encoded.  Add this to the code.. (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% "