# Uploadin Image - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

I have this code the I find on youtube xD my question is, how do I add an extra parameter?

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagen.image,0.0);
 NSString *urlString = @"http://urlexample.com/upload.php";
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
 [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [request setHTTPBody:body];

 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(returnString);
```

I try

`[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"extra=%@",info] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

hehehe im 100% new on this as you can see. please help me xD

Comment: can you please format your code. It is unreadable at all for me

Comment: :) Man im 100% noob on objective-c i just find that code on youtube

Comment: Do you want to add a parameter to the URL?

Comment: yah man and extra post data for the php file

like a comment of that image

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across [this earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326071/sending-a-post-request-from-cocoa-to-tumblr), and I think what you're looking for is something like this to add a field called foo and set it to bar:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo\"\r\n\r\nbar\n"]]];
```

Comment: yes someting like that but for some reason didnt work, i make a print_r($_POST) on php file to nslog the response and showme Array();