# Read Tumblr Dashboard

Tags: xml, cocoa, api, parsing, tumblr

Can somebody explain me how I can read the (or download it as XML at least) with cocoa?
I tried it like that. It might be totally wrong :).

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://larcus.tumblr.com/api/read"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
[request addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",[NSString MIMEBoundary]] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[request release];
```

In the connectionDidFinishLoading: method I'm just not able to parse the data.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a proper HTTP POST request.

Have a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326071/sending-a-post-request-from-cocoa-to-tumblr/2330248#2330248) for how to do it properly.