# iOS4 - problem urlencoding a string

Tags: ios4

I'm having a problem when trying to urlencode a string containing an ampersand.  I'm using the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *stadium = [[prefs stringForKey:@"stadiumname"] 
           stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Now, the original string going in is "Brighton & Hove", which is correct when I drop it into NSLog before it gets encoded.  After it's encoded, NSLog shows that it says "Brighton22ove", which is obviously failing when I pass it as a querystring.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I might have found the answer here actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-problem-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string but if anyone has any alternatives I'd be glad to hear them...

Comment: Doesn't seem as if that code is going to work, still getting odd results.

Comment: I've actually found the answer now at: http://cybersam.com/programming/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios

All the code and examples are on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the answer now at: cybersam.com/programming/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios All the code and examples are on that page