# How to pass "&" as string in a URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I am passing a string to service which sets some data to remote database. Everything works perfect as far as I don't have "&" in my string.

I am using this to pass the parameters:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString
 stringWithFormat:@"http://someservice.com/some/some_setstatus.php?status=active&name=%@",
 merchant] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

My guess is when it's checking the name with the name saved in the database, it's not able to find one because of '&'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-issue-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string

Comment: That's not clear enough and when implemented in my case doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192589/1226963 You need to create that category method then call that method on just your `merchant` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to pass "&", as it will be treated as a delimiter for URL parameters. "&" is a reserved character and you can consider encoding "&" as a combination of allowed characters. Take a look at [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856785/characters-allowed-in-a-url) question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `&` character for url (more info: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)
Have a look at https://github.com/tagyro/GTM/blob/master/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.h
This is a clone of Google Toolbox for Mac from their SVN.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to urlEncode to the string which will properly encode any special characters.  See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for more information.

Regards,

Steve