# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding does not escape "&"

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` to pass data to a php script. The problem is if the field has the char '&' in the text lets say: 'someone & cars', only the text "someone" is saved, everything after the '&' doesn't.

To create the string I use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, so I have like 5 field in the form and if I use `stringbyReplacingOcorrencesOfstring:@"&"`, what it does is replace the whole string not only the char '&' from the text field, so I get error.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone SDk : Issue with ampersand in the URL string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-issue-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string)

Comment: ASCII? What is this? 1980? Pray that the text never says "Es grünt so grün, wenn Spaniens Blüten blühen" ;-) Seriously: You should probably use UTF8 instead of ASCII.

Comment: :) well, I'll use from now on for sure but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` doesn't actually escape all necessary URL characters.

Instead, you can use the lower-level CoreFoundation function:

```
(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)myString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
```

or, when using ARC:

```
CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)myString, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
```

See [this post](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) for an example of a category on `NSString` that uses this function.

Answer (score 2):

Following works using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` if you want to specifically allow what would be encoded yourself. I'm using after base64 so this works fine.

```
NSString *charactersToEscape = @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" ";
NSCharacterSet *customEncodingSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charactersToEscape] invertedSet];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.test.com/more/test.html?name=john&age=28"];
NSString *encodedUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:customEncodingSet];
```