# POST required ampersand "&" in parameter for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, post, ampersand

I'm making a post with a required "&" in one of the parameters.  I've tried `%26` for **&** with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, as well as, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncodqing(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`.  Not working still.

```
let params = "designers=dolce%26gabbana"    
let nStr = params.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncodqing(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let postData = nStr?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
request.HTTPBody = postData
```

The string im posting is "Dolce & Gabbana"  and the server only recognizes it with the "&".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should try with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` cause `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncodqing` does not escapes all characters. By using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, you choose characters to escapes.

Example:

```
var encodedStr = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    nil,
    "Dolce & Gabbana",
    nil,
    "&", //you can add another special characters
    CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
)
```

[Here is another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-issue-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string) about this topic (in Objective-C)

Comment: Thanks!  how would i go about encoding it for the HTTPBody?   There's no .dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) for CFString

Comment: try to get first String by `let str = String(encodedStr)` then convert to `NSData` .

Comment: Can it be a problem in server side while decoding parameters?