# NSURL - encode '&' with spaces

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

Currently i am using the following way to encode the url

```
urlAndMethod.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

After encoding

```
http://103.50.154.52:8383/api/master/insta-list?category=Postpaid%20Mobile%20CDMA%20&%20Landline
```

How do i handle the special characters including '&'

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-issue-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.urlHostAllowed` characterset.

```
let escapedString = someString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```