# slash character ignored when send query string for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
ResponseHelper.Redirect("popup.aspx?file= "+ LogicLayer.ManualPath + _ddlPLCs.SelectedValue.ToString() + "\\" + _PLCRow[0][0].ToString() ,"_page", "menubar=0,width=100,height=100");
```

in the second page :

```
if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
        {
            LogicLayer.viewManual(Request.QueryString["file"].ToString());
        }
```

i found that slash `(\)` characters is removed from the file path

are there any idea ???

Comment: slash character was removed : d:\\folder1\\manuals\\pdfs\\file1.pdf >> became d:folder1 manuals pdfs file1.pdf

Comment: I don't think the backslash character is valid for HTTP URLs. You might change them to `%5C`. Also, you may want to try the `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) is not acceptable in a URL. You have to encode the characters to a %HEX value. In ASP.Net there is a method to encode a URL string, and one to decode the string.

In the View:

```
ResponseHelper.Redirect("popup.aspx?file= "+ System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(LogicLayer.ManualPath + _ddlPLCs.SelectedValue.ToString() + "\\" + _PLCRow[0][0].ToString()) ,"_page", "menubar=0,width=100,height=100");
```

In the Code Behind:

```
if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
{
   LogicLayer.viewManual(HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["file"].ToString()));
}
```

[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561954/asp-net-urlencode-ampersand-for-use-in-query-string).