# Unable Response.Redirect(url); with many query arguments

Tags: asp.net, redirect, query-string, sitecore

The '&' that separates query string arguments is getting **encoded** no mater what I do.

```
// sitecore ASP.NET server side ascx code...
string url = string.Format("http://other-domain.com/?a={0}&b={1}", "1", "2");
Response.Redirect(url);
// ...
```

gives my browser the address:

```
http://other-domain.com/?a=1&amp;b=2
```

which is not what I want, I simply want:

```
http://other-domain.com/?a=1&b=2
```

Is it Response.Redirect() that is HTMLencoding my '&'?

And how do I get it to leave that separator alone?

Comment: Covers the same ground as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561954/asp-net-urlencode-ampersand-for-use-in-query-string - look at Server.UrlEncode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certain of one thing: this is **not** caused by Response.Redirect() or any of the other code that you posted.

There is probably something else wrong in the actual code.

Comment: Thanks, and you are right, My problem was an editor that was htmlEncoding to the file, but showing me the '&' on screen (i.e. sitecore's developer center editor):