# ASP.NET automatically converts & to &amp;

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html-encode

Minor issue, but it's driving me nuts nonetheless.

I'm building a url for a `<script>` tag include to be rendered on an ASP.NET page, something like this:

```
<script src='<%= string.Format("http://example.com/page.aspx?a={0}&b={1}&c={2:0.00}", A, B, C)%>' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Problem is when this is rendered, the `&` characters are replaced with `&amp;`:

```
<script src='http://example.com/page.aspx?a=xxx&amp;b=zzz&amp;c=123.45' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I was expecting this, obviously:

```
<script src='http://example.com/page.aspx?a=xxx&b=zzz&c=123.45' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

However, if I render the url directly, outside the `<script>` tag, it looks ok! Just doing

```
<%= string.Format("http://example.com/page.aspx?a={0}&b={1}&c={2:0.00}", A, B, C) %>
```

Renders this:

```
http://example.com/page.aspx?a=xxx&b=zzz&c=123.45
```

What gives? And how do I stop this madness? My OCD can't take it!

Comment: This isn't an issue. It is for app security. `<head runat='server'>` html control convert/escape special chars into entity reference.

Comment: I tried with a plain HTML page also: Same thing, the & is replaced.

Comment: once try `<%` instead of `<%=`.. (I dont know much about it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Falkon and @AVD have said, ASP.NET is automatically doing the "right" thing in the `<script>` tag. See the w3c recommendation - [C.12. Using Ampersands in Attribute Values (and Elsewhere)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/guidelines.html#C_12)

> In order to ensure that documents are compatible with historical HTML user agents and XML-based user agents, ampersands used in a document that are to be treated as literal characters must be expressed themselves as an entity reference (e.g. "`&amp;`").

I'm not entirely sure why ASP.NET doesn't do the same thing in the rest of the page (could be any number of good reasons), but at least it's correcting the ampersand in the script tag. Conclusion: While you may be cursing ASP.NET for "scrambling" your url, you may want to thank it instead for helping your webpage be standards compliant.

Comment: I'm sure i would thank it if it was a URL, but it's not a lot of fun when it's javascript its breaking

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `MvcHtmlString.Create()` or `Html.Raw()`?

```
<script src='<%= MvcHtmlString.Create("http://example.com/page.aspx?a={0}&b={1}&c={2:0.00}", A, B, C)%>' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

or

```
<script src='<%= Html.Raw("http://example.com/page.aspx?a={0}&b={1}&c={2:0.00}", A, B, C)%>' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can work it out. I just make a method:

```
    public void BuildUrl(String baseUrl = "", String data = "")
    {
        Response.Write(baseUrl + data);
    }
```

and use it in my html page like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn_new" ref="<% this.BuildUrl(this.BaseUrl + "Master/Tanker_Edit.aspx?", "type=new&unique_id=" + Session.SessionID); %>">New</button>
```

The result:

```
<button type="button" class="btn_new" ref="http://kideco.local/Master/Tanker_Edit.aspx? type=new&unique_id=emxw1pkpnwcxpn1cl2cf04zv">
```

Answer (score 0):

"&" is a reserved character in HTML and XML, and consequently ASP.NET. The "&" gets converted by ASP.NET to `&amp`; because that is the code to display that character on the web.

You might find your answer in the answers on this question : [ASP.Net URLEncode Ampersand for use in Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561954/asp-net-urlencode-ampersand-for-use-in-query-string)

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: The web browser does not convert the & to &amp;. This is done by the asp.net runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Around the comment use `Server.HtmlEncode( yourString )`

It will automatically escape the double or single quotes for you, as well as ampersands (&) and less-than and greater-than signs, etc.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help either. :)

Comment: perhaps: `stringVariable.Replace ("&","&nbsp;")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<%=`, which can sometimes automatically HTMLEncode things it writes to the response stream, try using `<$:`. This is a new(ish) code expression nugget syntax added with ASP.Net 4.0. This new syntax will still HTMLEncode most things by default, but there is a special [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) interface you can use to explicitly tell this new nugget that you do **not** want to HTMLEncode this data, and thus avoid double encoding. You should pretty much always use the newer `<%:` and pretty much never use the older `<%=`... though of course there will be exceptions to this.

More details are available here:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx