# Getting ampersand through W3C Validation

Tags: escaping, w3c-validation, ampersand

My website menu structure contains query strings and obviously the `&` sign. The full menu HTML is

```
 <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male" class="inactive" runat="server">Men</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=Coats" runat="server">Coats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=Jeans" runat="server">Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=Knitwear" runat="server">Knitwear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=Shoes" runat="server">Shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=T-Shirts" runat="server">T-Shirts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female" class="inactive" runat="server">Women</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female&amp;Type=Coats" runat="server">Coats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female&amp;Type=Jeans" runat="server">Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female&amp;Type=Knitwear" runat="server">Knitwear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female&amp;Type=Shoes" runat="server">Shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Female&amp;Type=T-Shirts" runat="server">T-Shirts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids" class="inactive" runat="server">Kids</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=Coats" runat="server">Coats</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=Jeans" runat="server">Jeans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=Knitwear" runat="server">Knitwear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=Shoes" runat="server">Shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=T-Shirts" runat="server">T-Shirts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="~/Stores.aspx" runat="server">Stores</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/Contact.aspx" runat="server">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

As you can see I have correctly escaped the ampersand sign. However, when I run the page through the W3C validator, I get 15 errors saying...

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as & amp; .)

These 15 errors are for every line where the & amp; is in my HTML. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Your example validates in http://validator.w3.org/ as HTML5 (except for the `runat` attributes).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. This is for a university assignment so my tutor will run the url through the validator - that's when I get the errors.

Comment: Then you need to show us the actual HTML that gives this error.

Comment: `Line 33, Column 67: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)`

`<li><a href="Products.aspx?Gender=Male&Type=Coats">Coats</a></li>`

That is one of the errors but I have 17 others that are all relating to the & in my menu links. Thanks

Comment: The `&` in your code you just posted in the comment has to be encoded (like you do in the code in your question). -- Your question must include the code that gives errors in the W3C validator, so please [edit] it to include the (ideally, minimal) example that does not validate.

Comment: Hi, I have amended my original question to make it clearer

Comment: Again, this code does not produce the error you quote (as you can check with a minimal example in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28995435/1591669)). Is this really the final HTML you are validating, or is this the HTML *before* the server processed it somehow?

Comment: Ah I apologize I see what you mean now. The code in my original post is straight from Visual Studio. It is an ASP.NET web form page. When run in a browser, the link in your example (correctly?) changes to `<a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&Type=Coats">Coats</a>` replacing the & amp;

When the page is then put through the validator, the error occurs. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see. I don’t know ASP.NET, but maybe it would escape ampersands automatically in links? Did you try *not* to escape them yourself? (Maybe [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13737902/1591669).)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the `runat` attributes (which are not allowed in HTML), your code is valid HTML5.

You have correctly escaped `&` in URLs with `&amp;`. The error you quote does not result from the code in your question.

Minimal example that you may check with [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>
  <a href="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Kids&amp;Type=Coats">Coats</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using ASP.NET Hyperlink controls instead of standard HTML

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Products.aspx?Gender=Male&amp;Type=Coats">Coats</asp:HyperLink></li>
```