# Add space to a variable to be used in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a space in between the arrows but when I load the page there is no space between the arrows? I've tried adding the `&nbsp;` inside the string but it ends up using that as text?

```
@{
var hero_statement = "We grow companies from code.";
var hero_message = "We offer talented teams to deliver results from intricate ideas.";
var action_call = "Get Started";
var arrows = "<  / >";
}
<section id="hero" class="d-flex align-items-center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 pt-5 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-up">@hero_statement</h1>
            <div class="statement-arrows">@arrows</div>
            <h2 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">@hero_message</h2>
            <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800">
                <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">@action_call</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 order-1 order-lg-2 hero-img" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="200">
            <img src="img/hero-img.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The lessThan `<` and greaterThan `>` are special characters in HTML (and XML) and should be escaped (`&lt;` & `&gt;` respectively), this may be why `&nbsp;` didn't work for you. You should try `var arrows = "&lt;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&gt;";`

Comment: You just need @Html.Raw(arrows) (put &nbsp; instead of space in arrows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET automatically converts & to &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737902/asp-net-automatically-converts-to-amp)

Comment: "&lt;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&gt;"; doesn't seem to work @phuzi

Comment: Do not treat the arrows as a single HTML node. Put each arrow in its own container and then add whatever padding to the containers you want. Change ```<div class="statement-arrows">@arrows</div>``` to ```<div class="statement-arrows"><span>&lt;</span><span style="padding-left:10px;">&gt;</span></div>```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string in two and combine it with `&nbsp;` in your div

Comment: Tried using  var arrows = ""<--" & nbsp; "/  -->""; doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in the html code?

```
<h2 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">&nbsp;@hero_message</h2>
```

Comment: Just tried <div class="statement-arrows">&nbsp;@arrows</div> but doesn't work

Comment: &nbsp; + @arrows plus in between? not sure how that var is fed in there

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 <div class="statement-arrows">@Html.Raw(arrows.Replace(" ","&nbsp;"))</div>
```