# asp.net core Identity ConfirmEmailModel does not bind values correctly OnGetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, identity

I have a .net core Blazor project where I have scaffolded Identity into the project. I have customized IdentityUser to use integer IDs instead of the default.

I have run into a strange problem with the functionality of confirming email via the default
https://localhost:44348/identity/account/manage/email page

this built-in page has a button which posts to OnPostSendVerificationEmailAsync as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSendVerificationEmailAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            "/Account/ConfirmEmail", 
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code },
            protocol: Request.Scheme);

        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
            email,
            "Confirm your email", HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl));

        //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
        //    email,
        //    "Confirm your email",
        //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

        StatusMessage = "Verification email sent. Please check your email.";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```

I have made slight modifications to the function however those changes should not affect the default mechanism of call-back URL generation. basically, this generates an email confirmation URL and sends an email to the indicated user account.

I receive the following generated URL to the mailbox:

https://localhost:44348/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=1&code=Q2ZESjhQcXM4RmJpR2xGT3I2NW41SUkxT0pXWnI5WlE5TUlhUndzSi9aQnA1ZGN4OTc5ZS9UOFFiR2xranhidFBWWTU2c3AxZ25peUYvamFaVUVhbG5ac3ArcHh5WkVNMVczUHVDQVBqMVdXUUFFeGdwU1FWZXo1eUxSVHZUU3dwb2RpUGVpTFhCTzhJSjhHR3ZpckVYNUZQMVJrUGhUU1FQOE52TnVWdU9jYVBKbXIyTkY4V05NVVhrVXVid2xQRFJzSTFRPT0

however, the problem is that the target ConfirmEmail does not bind userId and code correctly. the code part is null.

any bright ideas on the elephant in the room that I am unable to see here will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

[image: id is bound fine]

however, the code is null

[image: code is null]

Comment: adding this as a comment just for future reference however, i have not yet worked out what the resolution is. apparently this has been reported as a bug - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2152

Answer (score 1):

apparently, the problem is with the format of the BODY element of the email being sent. OK, step-by-step now.

this piece of code uses encoder which encodes the URL to follow the rules as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737902/asp-net-automatically-converts-to-amp)

```
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
            email,
            "Confirm your email",
            $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
```

part of what encoder does is it turns the ampersand into this: `&amp;`

according to  [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2152)

> The solution to this problem is setting the body as "html" and not "plain" because the email content is HTML and the callback URL generates HTML content which is sent as a plain email to the user.

If you set the content as HTML the '&' will be converted to '&' and the email will display the correct link.

i suppose they leave little option for people who would like to stick to PLAIN email body rather than HTML.