# sql count works only on single words, not multiple words

Tags: sql

I have been using this sql statement for quite some time. Just noticed it only works on single words.

```
sql = "SELECT Count(*) as Totalab FROM tablename WHERE city = '" & Server.URLEncode(rs("city")) & "'"
```

For example:

For the city of Brampton this works fine and returns 32 (just example), because Brampton is 1 word.
For the city of New York it returns 0 (where it should return 56, for example) because New York is 2 words.

Comment: What database you are working with ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561954/asp-net-urlencode-ampersand-for-use-in-query-string

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `OR` rather than `AND`?

Comment: how does your  query with two words work? It should probaby use an OR or IN e.g WHERE city IN ('brampton', 'new york')

Comment: Use parameters instead of munging queries with such values.

Comment: Gordon, could you point me in right direction

Comment: Alan, there is no OR or AND

Comment: Valli, thank you, but that's not it.

Comment: Without sample data, and results related to that sample, AND which dbms this is for, I can't see you getting an answer. Why would you get 56 for "New York"? What about "Wotton-under-Edge"  or similar? [for more, see](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207787/united-kingdoms-three-name-cities-is-there-a-generic-way-to-write-them)

Comment: You're asking for SQL Injection attacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to identify the matching cities?  If so, why not try using WHERE EXISTS conditions?

```
SELECT Totalab
FROM table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT City FROM Table WHERE CityId = 
SomeValue AND State = XX);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is VB, that's because you're not querying the database with `New York`.

You're actually querying it with `New+York`.

That's because, for whatever strange reason, [you're URL Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx) the string, which is replacing the space () with a plus (`+`).

If, for whatever reason, you're dealing with encoded parameters, you should be **decoding** them, although presumably whatever framework you're using will already be doing that for you anyways.

Really, though, I'd be far more concerned about SQL Injection, which is a likely problem if you're simply concatenating the strings.  You need to be using prepared statements, which might also solve whatever problem you think you're dealing with here.